# Server Error with PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

Not sure what is causing the error. I have tried several times but continue to get the error. Any help welcome. Thank you.

Here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="modalcontact.php">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="NAME" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP under modalcontact.php file in my hosting server:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'L|D Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'myemail@email.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from L|D Contact ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }


// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

Comment: do you have access to the apache/iis logs?

Comment: Having `the error` would be very useful.

Comment: I'm not sure about the logs. Right now i'm getting a blank page when loading 'modalcontact.php', so I guess thats an imporvement from the 500 internal server error.

Comment: So maybe the `submit` isn't submitting? Not sure but all answers will be guesses unless you can provide an error message.

Comment: @chris85, At this point, im not getting an error. After clicking submit, the page goes blank with the /modalcontact.php at the end of the URL

Comment: The page shows blank when there IS an error. Errors display has probably been turned off by default in the PHP config.

Comment: `$from` is not the correct format for argument 4 of `mail()`. That's supposed to be mail headers in a format like `"From: Name <account@domain.com>\r\n"`

Comment: I'll keep working at it. Thank you for the responses

Comment: I'm back to "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Comment: Follow the message `More information about this error may be available in the server error log`. We can't just guess at what might be wrong (I guess we could, not a good use of time though).

Comment: Any thoughts on this error:PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in [myfile.php] on line 30

Answer (score 0):

Try this code replace the from with header:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: abc@gmail.com';
```

I tested your code and it works fine. Then what's problem on your server...

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thank you.